# Stop Outlook 2007 from pulling the entire inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have several users who are complaining that Outlook just sits there and pulls their entire email history from the exchange server.  Some of them have 2.6 GB of emails that need to be pulled over the wireless.  Is there anyway that some of these can be pulled the way they are in Thunderbird where only the headers are pulled and not the entire emails, attachments and all?

Comment: Per the [faq]; Super User is not about issues specific to corporate IT support and networks. This is an Exchange server question so I have tagged it to get migrated to the proper forum to get answered.

Comment: @CharlieRB Exchange is now available for regular users as well, so I would not VTC as OT yet. Outlook is a product the regular user would use, so I would not VTC

Comment: What type of account are they using to connect?  If it's an Exchange connection, then is Cached Mode enabled or disabled on the client(s)?  Is it pulling all mail every time they open Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If outlook download their entire mailbox and does that every time then something is wrong with the setup.

You can configure outlook in many ways (imap, pop3, webmail, etc), but assuming you configured it in the default way it will connect to an exchange server, download all mail **once** and keep that in a cache files (.ost) .

The next time it will only downloaded changes.

Thus, either:

- Reconfigure outlook to connect over the LAN to an exchange server.
- Check that the users can write to their profile
- or move part of their mail to a .pst file (move, not copy) and keep that on the local host.

In addition: 2,6GB is a lot. Is that all their mail? Can you teach them how to archive mail? A setup where outlook automatically collects all mail older than a year and moves it to an archive takes 5 minutes to set up.

Comment: Yeah it's closer to like 3.6 GB...but your suggestion of archiving the mail was a great idea.

Comment: My backups loved the "archive2004-2008.pst" folders. No more changes in them, no more tape space for incremental backups. But it was a lot of work to explain it to the users.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this....